# Mootools: How to stop showing and error when the element/div dont exist

Tags: javascript, mootools

The js code is in the footer and when the div is not on the page it shows an error. This only happens when i'm using `$('id-of-the-div')` not `$$('#id-of-the-div')`. And the error stop the hole script.

Js code

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {  



    $('id-of-the-div').addEvent('click', function() { 

          alert('click');
        });

});
```

Error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEvent' of null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an element reference returns an object or null. if null, it won't be truthy. you can check for that like you would for any property of the current context object:

pattern one:

```
var el = $('someel');
if (el) { 
    el.addEvent({ ... });
}

// or 
if (!el) return;

// or 
el && el.addEvent({ });
```

pattern 2, use event delegation by assigning the event to a parent element

```
$('main').addEvent('click:relay(#otherid)', function(event, otherel){

});
```

pattern 3: collections don't iterate when no items:

```
$$('#someid').addEvent('click', fn);
```

when not found, the above won't call the addEvent at all.

pattern 1 is the most common